# I need to show multiple axis, which is having constant values in the x-axis and dynamic values in y-axises

Tags: highcharts

I need to show multiple axis, which is having constant values in the x-axis and dynamic values in y-axises

1. 1st y-axis regarding bubble chart [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VAIBk.jpg)
2. 2nd y-axis regarding column chart

We got requriment like to show them side by side not like merged as shown in second refrenece picture.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VAIBk.jpg)
Implemented bubble and column chart in one chart using 2 y-axis and 1 x-axis. We got chart as show in reference.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qKyFK.jpg)
Both are getting mergged instead we want to show them side by side.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create column and bubble series with, each with own y-axis. Use `pointPlacement` property to position columns next to bubbles.

```
    series: [{
        type: 'column',
        pointPadding: 0.4,
        pointPlacement: 0.3,
        data: [70, 50, 65],
        yAxis: 1
    }, {
        type: 'bubble',
        data: [3, 2, 3]
    }]
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/pwq3shef/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.pointPlacement

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.pointPadding